# Window function in R

Tags: r

I have table

```r
DF <- tibble(
  CLIENT = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  N_DOG = c('N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9'),
  DT = as.Date(c('01.06.2021','12.07.2021','04.05.2021',
                 '03.08.2021','21.07.2021','04.01.2022',
                 '07.04.2021','09.11.2021','08.12.2021'), format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
  RANK = c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3)
)
```

| CLIENT | N_DOG | DT | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N1 | 2021-06-01 | 1 |
| 1 | N2 | 2021-07-12 | 1 |
| 1 | N3 | 2021-05-04 | 2 |
| 2 | N4 | 2021-08-03 | 3 |
| 2 | N5 | 2021-07-21 | 1 |
| 2 | N6 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |
| 3 | N7 | 2021-04-07 | 2 |
| 3 | N8 | 2021-11-09 | 2 |
| 3 | N9 | 2021-12-08 | 3 |

> I want to find a contract for each client according to the following criteria:
>
> 1. Find a contract with a minimum rank
> 2. If there are several such contracts, we take the last one.

> PS. The output must be a unique client and 1 contract

Realization :

```r
MIN_RANK <- DF %>% 
  select(CLIENT, RANK) %>% 
  group_by(CLIENT) %>% 
  filter(RANK == min(RANK)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()

MIN_RANK %>% 
  inner_join(DF, by = c('CLIENT','RANK')) %>% 
  select(!c(N_DOG,RANK)) %>% 
  group_by(CLIENT) %>% 
  filter(DT == max(DT)) %>% 
  inner_join(DF, by = c('CLIENT','DT'))
```

Output

| CLIENT | DT | N_DOG | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-12 | N2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-04 | N6 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-09 | N8 | 2 |

How can I do it faster ? [ maybe there's some function ? ]
the same [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385086/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-r) at the ru forums.

`English is not my native language, so please be kind to my mistakes.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arrange in the desired order and select the first of each client?

```
arrange(DF, CLIENT, RANK, desc(row_number())) |>
    filter(!duplicated(CLIENT))
```

If there are many additional columns in `DF`, it might pay to do the operations just on the CLIENT, RANK, and row number, e.g.,

```
row_number <- seq_len(nrow(DF))
o <- order(DF$CLIENT, DF$RANK, rev(row_number))
i <- !duplicated(DF$CLIENT[o])
## place the row_number in the correct order and subset to include
## non-duplicated CLIENT; return these rows
DF[row_number[o][i],]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.table::setDT(DF)[order(RANK,-DT), .SD[1], by=CLIENT]
```

Output:

```
   CLIENT  N_DOG         DT  RANK
    <num> <char>     <Date> <num>
1:      2     N6 2022-01-04     1
2:      1     N2 2021-07-12     1
3:      3     N8 2021-11-09     2
```